# How do i remove Business feeds Shortcode fatal error

Tags: shortcode

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /opt/lampp/htdocs/news/wp-content/plugins/iron_elements/vc_extend/shortcode/wwn_business_feeds.php on line 13

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists('wwn_currency_updates')):
    function wwn_currency_updates($atts) {
        ob_start();
        $attr = shortcode_atts(array('currency' => esc_html__('USD', 'worldwidenews'),
            'css' => esc_html__('', 'worldwidenews'),
        ), $atts);
        $css_class = apply_filters(VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, vc_shortcode_custom_css_class($attr['css'], ' '), 'wwn_currency_updates', $atts);
        $currency_base = $attr['currency'];
        $current_ping = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=" . $currency_base;
        $currency = wp_remote_get($current_ping);
        if ($currency) {
            $currency_data = json_decode($currency['body']); ?>
            <div class="<?php echo esc_attr($css_class); ?>">
                <div class="wwn-currency-update-wrapper">
                    <div class="sub-heading-sec">
                        <h6><?php esc_html_e('Currency Rates', 'worldwidenews'); ?></h6>
                    </div><!--sub-heading-sec-->
                    <div class="wwn-currency-rates-sec">
                        <ul class="wwn-currency-rates-info">
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - AUD (Australian Dollars)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->AUD) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->AUD) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - CAD (Canadian Dollar)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->CAD) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->CAD) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - EUR (Euro)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->EUR) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->EUR) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - NZD (New Zealand Dollar)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->NZD) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->NZD) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - INR (Indian Rupees)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->INR) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->INR) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - SGD (Singapore Dollar)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->SGD) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->SGD) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - BGN (Bulgarian Lev)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->BGN) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->BGN) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - RON (Romanian)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->RON) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->RON) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="wwn-currency wwn-left-float">
                                    <?php esc_html_e('GBP (Sterling) - CHF (Swiss Franc)', 'worldwidenews'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="wwn-currency-rates wwn-right-float">
                                    <?php echo isset($currency_data->rates->CHF) ? esc_html($currency_data->rates->CHF) : 0; ?>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--wwn-currency-rates-sec-->
                </div><!--currency-update-wrapper-->
            </div>
        <?php }
        $currency_updates = ob_get_clean();
        return $currency_updates;
    }

    add_shortcode('wwn_currency_updates', 'wwn_currency_updates');
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the issue:

```
$currency = wp_remote_get($current_ping);
if($currency){
```

`$currency` will either be a `WP_Error` object or an `array`. Checking `if($currency)` will be true in both cases.

Instead, you should check if it's an array and not an error object:

```
if ( is_array( $currency ) && ! is_wp_error( $currency ) ) {
```

of course, that won't fix the fact that `wp_remote_get` returns an error...

Comment: now it gives currency 0 all the country.

Comment: well like I said, I can't tell you why it's not returning currency data. you need to debug the `wp_remote_get` response yourself.